# Are all proper classes the same in NBG-like theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm learning set theory first time, with 'A Book of Set Theory' by Charles C. Pinter. In that book, definition 1.9 states the definition of equality of classes. For any two classes $A, B$, we define the equality by $$A = B\iff (\forall X)[A\in X\implies B\in X\text{ and }B\in X\implies A\in X].$$ So, if $A, B$ are two proper classes, then for any class $X$, $A\in X$ and $B\in X$ is false, since they cannot be an element of any class. Hence by definition, I concluded that $A = B$.

My question is, is it really true that all the proper classes are same, by assuming NBG(I've heard that Pinter's book is based on this) or other set theory? If not, does proper classes allow contradiction in this system? Or have I made some mistake in reasoning? Please give me some insight. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure $A\in X\iff B\in X$ shouldn't be $X\in A\iff X\in B$?

Comment: @J.G. Yep I checked it many times,,, this book later states the Axiom of Extent that $A=B\iff (\forall x)[x\in A\iff x\in B]$.

Comment: Consider the two proper classes $\text {On} = \{ x \mid x \text { is an Ordinal } \}$ and $V = \{ x \mid x=x \}$. Are they equal?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I haven't learn them yet, but I understand you are saying that those are different. But that's what I'm asking. What is the source of problem? Is my book wrong? Is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: Yes, IMO the def is wrong. According to it, all proper classes are equal, but not every set is an ordinal, and thus $V \ne \text {On}$

Comment: @riemann18 I wasn't suggesting you'd misread Pinter, but that Pinter may have a misprint.

Comment: @J.G. Ah ok. But as I wrote in above comment, that's almost impossible. He even distinguished X and x to designate element in Axiom of Extent.

Comment: @riemann18 Be that as it may, the only way the claimed result could hold is if there are "super classes" (over which $\forall X$ quantified) to which proper classes can belong, which doesn't sound very NBG-like to me.

Comment: @J.G. Hmm.... well that's a good point. This book do not deal with formal logic of quantifiers. We just assume it is possible and proceed. So I don't know how quantification is defined or used formally. But does quantification require the class of quantified things?

Comment: @riemann18 Let's compare NBC to ZF for a moment. In ZF, we quantify over sets, which are always elements of some set. In NBG, we quantify over classes, and $X$ is a set iff some class $Y$ satisfies $X\in Y$. In the former case, it's taken as an axiom that sets are equal iff they have the same elements, but it can be proven they're equal iff the same sets have them as elements.

Answer (score 1):

A *class* $C$ is specified by: $C= \{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}$.

Thus $C=D ↔ \forall x (\varphi(x) ↔ \psi(x))$.

If we used the set-builder notation, according to which $z \in \{ x \mid \varphi(x) \} \leftrightarrow \varphi(z)$, we have that:

> $C= D ↔ \forall z (z \in \{ x \mid \varphi(x) \} ↔ z \in \{ x \mid \psi(x) \})$;

see e.g. [Mendelson](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Introduction_to_Mathematical_Logic/FS-sCQAAQBAJ?hl=it&gbpv=1&dq=mendelson+logic&pg=PA232), page 232.

The same definition of *class equality* is used by [Paul Bernays](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Axiomatic_Set_Theory/IopfGCCME6wC), page 51 (the "B" of $\mathsf {NBG}$) and similarly for the axiom used by [Kurt Gödel](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Consistency_of_the_Axiom_of_Choice_a/rXjGFI6IvvkC?hl=it&gbpv=1&dq=G%C3%B6del,+The+Consistency+of+the+Axiom+of+Choice+and+of+the+Generalized+Continuum+Hypothesis+with+the+Axioms+of+Set+Theory&pg=PA3) (the "G" of $\mathsf {NBG}$).